# How to resize a linux container in proxmox

Tags: lxc, proxmox

I'm trying to change an lxc container size in new proxmox 4 on debian jessie.
But there is no checkbox (which was in openvz containers) for changing a size from proxmox interface.
Changing a size in lxc container configuration file and restarting the services won't help.
Backing up a container and then restoring it doesn't give an option of changing a size as well.

Answer (score 7):

According to proxmox forum, you can do this with command line :

`pct resize <vmid> <disk> <size> [OPTIONS]`

where `disk` is usually `rootfs` and `size` can use suffixes like `500G`. More details in the help: `pct help resize`

http://web.archive.org/web/20151114072949/http://forum.proxmox.com/threads/23792-how-to-add-and-or-resize-a-LXC-disk